# can i handle csv file in django view ,i dont want to creat a model for csv file

Tags: python, django, file

I have a decision tree algorithm which trained itself by the data stored in a csv file,now I am using django to create a simple web program which receive test data from the web page and then django will process the input and  redirect to the result web page which contains the result predicted by the algorithm. Now I get stuck when I am trying to read csv file in view.py:
this is the project structure:

[image: structure]

as the above picture show, I put the mybtrain.csv(trainning data file I am trying to read) under 'mysite'

then i write some code in view.py,as following:

[image]

the IDE just tell, cannot find the csv file, then I put the mybtrain under the determineSafety which is the only app I created, still does not work, so I just want to ask:

**Does my way can work if I modify something or this just does not on the right track?**

Comment: Please edit your post to replace images with actual code (or text for the project's structure).

Answer (score 0):

to get path to your csv file you can try something like this

```
import os

filepath = '{REAL_PATH}/{CSV_PATH}'.format(
    REAL_PATH=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),
    CSV_PATH='path/to/mybtrain.csv'
)
```

where REAL_PATH will be path to your `views.py`

Comment: @gloriaxie np, let me know did it solved the problem or not.